# Display issues with Sencha Touch and IE10 on Windows phones

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm having major issues with the Sencha Touch 2.3 framework in IE10. I have a client which is waiting for me to ensure this works on Windows phone as it currently does on iPhone/Android. I'm now left wishing I hadn't picked the framework as what already works in Chrome and WebKit doesn't work in IE even though I've upgraded to the latest 2.3 framework.

I have a simple login form which shows up blank in IE. The toolbar is displaying correctly but fields + buttons are simply not present.  All forms which have some kind of control or panel is not being displayed at all.

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**
To try and ascertain what the problem is I'm testing the Kitchen Sink demo in IE10 and the results are even worse than my own app!

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/forms

What hope is there for me if their own demo doesn't work?

Comment: I actually prefer avoiding IE at all, its the devil's browser. :)

Comment: I agree, however Windows Phone uses IE so I can't really ignore that;)

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge and experience with Sencha Touch 2:

- iOS: reliable, fast and responsive.
- Android: reliable but slow and unresponsive. For small app, it's somehow acceptable. For large app, it's not.
- Windows Phone: unreliable at all. The kitchen sink demo doesn't work on WP 8 on my device, but then it works partially after ungrading to 8.1, but the performance is terrible.

So don't go with Sencha Touch (or more generally, in my opinion, any cross-platform solution) if you're tending to build a large app with complex logics & sophisticated animations while keeping the performance great.

Comment: I've invested quite a bit in developing their application on the basis that it would eventually support WP and unfortunately it doesn't. How do I explain this to the client?!

Comment: I oftenly give them a disclaimer about its current performance and platform support range. Although what they advertised is "Sencha Touch blurs the lines between native and web apps", clients should be aware of the fact that the performance is only fast on iOS. For other platforms, either it's very sluggish, or you will take SO MUCH time for optimization, which causes your app less scalable and thus loses the essential advantage over native apps.

Comment: Ok thanks. I hope no-one goes down the same route as me and gets bitten!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that ExtJS and Sencha Touch, alike, sometimes need the height and/or width of some components set to display properly in IE. Do this for the top-most component that isn't displaying. Usually, it's good enough to set both height and width to 100% rather than using a specific pixel value.

For example:

```
Ext.define('Login.view.LoginForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    config: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        items: [
            //other stuff
        ]
     }
});
```

With that being said, as Thiem has touched on and you've discovered, IE's performance is abysmal with Sencha Touch, even if you somehow manage to get everything to display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus on IE design issue by giving support for CSS on DOM elements and have look on listeners. In kitchen sink they gave support to browsers like chrome,safari. These browser gives full fledged support for modern css3 and advanced JS by default. To additional reference check [this](http://css3test.com/).